# meteor minified with production flag fails to load certain files

Tags: deployment, meteor

I am not getting any errors from the server or the browser console but my application seems to break when i minify or use the `--production` flag. I have went back to a revision/changeset that i recall working with `meteor deploy` and it still fails. Has anyone else faced this problem ?

I should mention, i just ran this with an older version of meteor and it works. Meteor version 0.7.0.1 looks like might be the problem?

EDIT: Running 0.6.6.3

I ran `meteor --release 0.6.6.3 --production` to minify and use an older version of meteor. This works perfectly, any one know if the bundling process has changed in the latest version of meteor ?

Comment: Can you define "break"? Are there errors on the console (if so what errors)?

Comment: I also get the same problem

Comment: While this could be a bug, can't do anything without seeing some reproduction code.

Comment: @DavidWeldon no errors on both the browser console and the server output.

Comment: @emgee what do you mean by reproduction code ? The entire application fails with even the smallest change that was deploying for me months ago. I will try to reproduce with a fresh project

Comment: What is the latest version of meteor that it works with?

Comment: @alanning I have confirmed it works with 0.6.6.1

Comment: @waitingkuo Have you managed to get this working. any other ideas?

Comment: @Warz, can you put together a small example that displays the problem and publish it to github?  That way we can help debug further.

Comment: @alanning I will see if i can reproduce this, from the meteor group i think the culprit was the minification process having problems with `@import` statements for those using custom fonts.

Comment: @Warz, way back with v0.6.4.1 we had issues if we had `@media` statements split across multiple files.  Putting them all in one file avoided the css minification problems.  May work for your `@import` statements as well...

Comment: @alanning Do you want to post your comment as an answer. I looked back at all my `@import` statements and found one that was commented out and saw that in production my css file had been corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way back with v0.6.4.1 we had issues if we had `@media` statements split across multiple files. Putting them all in one file avoided the css minification problems. May work for your `@import` statements as well.

-- update --

"I looked back at all my @import statements and found one that was commented out and saw that in production my css file had been corrupted."  @Warz in comments

So it looks like commenting out @import statements is not supported in the css minifier as of Meteor v0.7.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Something went wrong while minified javascript files. I temporarily deploy without minifying to avoid this kind of problems:

```
meteor deploy --debug yoursite.meteor.com
```

Comment: There is a known issue as the `css-minification` branch is actively being worked on. Unfortunately I can't deploy to production with that flag, i reverted back to an older version of meteor.

Comment: But the document says that you can deploy without minifying but giving `--debug`. Anything went wrong?

Comment: Using the `--debug` works for me, its that its meant for debugging purposes and I use it for prototyping meteor sites. The bundler is my issue, i want to minify and bundle when going into production