# Why does Meteor only load one CSS file after deployment?

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have half a dozen CSS files inside the folder "client/CSS". In the local server it works fine but after deployment the website only seem to load the bootstrap.min.css file. Has anyone come across this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Meteor tries to compile all the css files it finds into one file.  If you have css missing, meteor is probably failing on one of your files and giving up. When this has happened to me the issues were around unmatched brackets.

Try putting your css text into [CSSLint](http://csslint.net/) or something like it, one at a time, and see if they have errors.

Some [other discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864884/meteor-minified-with-production-flag-fails-to-load-certain-files) here that says @media and @imports lines might also be cause some issues depending on their use.

Comment: Thanks! That makes total sense.